# MySQL Dump/Import progress on Windows

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I'm going to dump a considerable big datatabase (7gb) from a MySQL 5.1 instance running on Windows into a .sql script and import it into a MySQL 5.5 instance, also on Windows (another machine). I'd like to be able to monitor the process of both operations, since I believe they are going to take some time to execute.

Apparentely, this feature has not yet made into the target MySQL versions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806435/how-to-implement-a-mysql-dump-restore-progress-bar). I also checked the solution suggested [here](http://lettucemodeengaged.com/mysql-dumprestore-progress-bar/), but it seems a lot of work (and also inserting more variables to this sensitive operation) to do something that should be simple.

By the time, ins't there any simple solution to monitor, somehow, the progress of these operations?

Comment: For the dump, I can only think to make a .NET filesystemwatcher task that notifies on file change. You won't be able to get a percentage but you'll be able to see that it's still working. For the other side you could set your session to `READ UNCOMMITTED` and `count(*)` the number of rows in your largest table. Not sure this is the best approach but it's just an idea. Alternatively, you can use Task Manager to make sure the processes are still running.

Answer (score 4):

Restoration will be

- Per database (alphabetical order)
- Per table within each database (alphabetical order)

If you want to see the progress, you can run the following every few minutes:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

To be sure that restore is not blocked, use `SHOW PROCESSLIST`. It will show you the restore transactions (create table, insert into...).

You can also followed your disk space usage but this is'nt a really good metric...

Max.

Comment: This is most straightforward. +1 !!!